# LINQ in LinqPad count how many times a word shows up

Tags: linq, linqpad

I am trying to write a LINQ query that counts how many times `<p>` and `</p>` shows up.

```
    from d in IPACS_Documents
    join dp in IPACS_ProcedureDocs on d.DocumentID equals dp.DocumentID
    join p in IPACS_Procedures on dp.ProcedureID equals p.ProcedureID
    where d.DocumentID == 4
    & d.DateDeleted == null
    select ??
```

The select is where I am stuck.  The column I need to count how many times `<p>` is in `d.Html` the same for `</p>`

Comment: How many times "<p>" shows up in the entire record set, or how many records have "<p>" in them?

Comment: The above query limits the response to one record, I want to know how many times "<p>" shows up in d.html. @StevenV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a Linq-To-SQL/Entities way to complete this, since SQL doesn't do this easily.

```
var result = (from d in IPACS_Documents
join dp in IPACS_ProcedureDocs on d.DocumentID equals dp.DocumentID
join p in IPACS_Procedures on dp.ProcedureID equals p.ProcedureID
where d.DocumentID == 4
&& d.DateDeleted == null
select d.Html).First();

int count = Regex.Matches(result, "<p>|</p>").Count;
```

will probably do it.

Comment: That did it.  Just as I feared 338 `<p>'s` and only 147 `</p>'s`.

Comment: @JamesWilson Sounds like a long day ahead of you... Good luck.